# Is there a way to uniquely identify USB storage devices in Windows (Powershell)?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, powershell

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/939674/unique-identifier-for-usb-drive-in-powershell) talks about what purports to be a unique id for USB volumes in PowerShell. There seems to be an obvious problem. Volumes are created by the OS, so there is no way to guarantee against a collision if the script is run on another system. It seems that the only way to guarantee against collisions is to use some associator of either Win32_DiskDrive of Get_Disk to connect physical media to volumes. Has anyone one this? Alternately, is there some unique ID for either storage media or logical volume that I'm missing?

Comment: What wrong with using the SerialNumber as described in the answer to the linked question?

Comment: Like I said, to the best of my knowledge it is assigned by the OS. If the script is run on another OS with the same device, I have a low-probability but nonzero chance of a collision.

Comment: From the linked answer "Finally I inserted the sticks into another computer, note that the deviceId is different, but the serial number remains the same."

Comment: Yes, and there is nothing there that guarantees against 2 volumes being assigned the same serial by 2 different windows installs.

Comment: The serial number is not assigned by the OS.

Comment: How is this possible, if the volume is created by the OS? Or, do you claim that any volume on a usb stick will have the same serial? How can that be if the stick has more than one volume? Could you please doument this claim somehow?

Comment: Answer provided.

Comment: The volume is created by the OS, but the USB device is created by the manufacturer.  I presume that the code in the OS that creates a volume uses the serial number provided by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there some unique ID for either storage media or logical volume that I'm missing?

> It seems that the only way to guarantee against collisions is to use some associator of either Win32_DiskDrive of Get_Disk to connect physical media to volumes

The answer [Unique identifier for USB drive in Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/939674/unique-identifier-for-usb-drive-in-powershell) by [Windos](https://superuser.com/users/36030/windos) suggests using the SerialNumber:

> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | select Name, DeviceID, SerialNumber

However, some manufacturers:

- Don't provide a serial number at all, or
- Use the same serial number in many devices.

---

#### Solution: Use SerialNumber together with Physical Media and Volume

We can tie together the Device ID, Model, Partition Data, Volume ID, and Serial Number as demonstrated by the following PowerShell Script (based on [Using WMI to link a Disk Volume to a Physical Disk with PowerShell](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/using-wmi-to-link-a-disk-volume-to-a-physical-disk-with-powershell/)).

This allows the generation of a unique ID for a Physical Disk.

**Get-DiskDetails.ps1**:

```
$diskdrive = Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive
foreach($drive in $diskdrive)
  {
  out-host -InputObject "`nDevice: $($drive.deviceid.substring(4))`n  Model: $($drive.model)"
  # partition
  $partitions = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($drive.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
  foreach($part in $partitions)
    {
    Out-Host -InputObject "  Partition: $($part.name)"
    $vols = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($part.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
    foreach($vol in $vols)
      {
      out-host -InputObject "  Volume: $($vol.name)"
      $serial = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | where { $_.Name -eq "$($vol.name)\" } | select SerialNumber
      out-host -InputObject "  Serial Number: $($serial.serialnumber)"
      }
    }
  }
```

**Sample output**:

```
> .\Get-DiskDetails.ps1

Device: PHYSICALDRIVE0
  Model: WDC WD5000LPVX-08V0TT5
  Partition: Disk #0, Partition #0
  Partition: Disk #0, Partition #1
  Partition: Disk #0, Partition #2
  Volume: C:
  Serial Number: 3369131806

Device: PHYSICALDRIVE1
  Model: SanDisk Cruzer USB Device
  Partition: Disk #1, Partition #0
  Volume: E:
  Serial Number: 2157441447

Device: PHYSICALDRIVE2
  Model: Seagate Expansion Desk USB Device
  Partition: Disk #2, Partition #0
  Volume: F:
  Serial Number: 911653731
>
```

Comment: Yes I will test this in the next 24 hours, I figured it was something like this.

Comment: Before I get too deep into experiments, what do you think will happen if I make two volumes on one usb drive? If they have different serials, clearly the serial _is_ from the os, no?

Comment: Guess what, this fails too. DeviceId is dynamically assigned even on local system. I had seen that site before and forgotten it. To confirm, just try to connect a couple of usb drives in various order.

Comment: @jamesson The serial is only provided by the OS if the device itself doesn't provide one. Most manufactures do provide one.